# Convert list of Pandas Dataframe JSON objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe with one column where each cell in the column is a JSON object.

```
    players
0   {"name": "tony", "age": 57}
1   {"name": "peter", age": 46}
```

I want to convert this to a data frame as:

```
name      age
tony      57
peter     46
```

Any ideas how I do this?

Note: the original JSON object looks like this...

```
{
"players": [{
        "age": 57,
        "name":"tony"    
    },
    {
        "age": 46,
        "name":"peter"    
    }]
}
```

Comment: What does your json object look like? The reason I ask is it should be possible to go fro json object directly to your dataframe.. This extra step is inefficient.

Comment: @jpp question updated

Answer (score 3):

Use `DataFrame` constructor if `type`s of values are `dict`s:

```
#print (type(df.loc[0, 'players']))
#<class 'str'>

#import ast
#df['players'] = df['players'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

print (type(df.loc[0, 'players']))
<class 'dict'>

df = pd.DataFrame(df['players'].values.tolist())
print (df)
   age   name
0   57   tony
1   46  peter
```

But better is use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) from `json`s object as suggested @jpp:

```
json = {
"players": [{
        "age": 57,
        "name":"tony"    
    },
    {
        "age": 46,
        "name":"peter"    
    }]
}

df = json_normalize(json, 'players')
print (df)
   age   name
0   57   tony
1   46  peter
```

Answer (score 1):

This can do it:

```
df = df['players'].apply(pd.Series)
```

However, it's slow:

```
In [20]: timeit df.players.apply(pd.Series)
1000 loops, best of 3: 824 us per loop
```

@jezrael suggestion is faster:

```
In [24]: timeit pd.DataFrame(df.players.values.tolist())
1000 loops, best of 3: 387 us per loop
```

Comment: Better is do timings in 1000rows :) There is difference better see ;)

Comment: @jezrael I'll try to do that when I have some time :). I upvoted your answer so the OP's accept it